# Can I modify iTerm window titles for some but not all running commands?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, high-sierra, iterm

I was looking for a solution to auto set custom title in the terminal based on what command is being run on the current terminal. So, rather than java showing in many tabs - I'd love to have it pick apart which java program is running not that all say just java.

I found very [interesting and different answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104018/set-dynamic-window-title-based-on-command-input) yet not fully useful for my requierment

currently, I have written below line in `~/.bash_profile`

```
trap 'printf "\033]0;%s\007" "${BASH_COMMAND//[^[:print:]]/}"' DEBUG
```

which works somewhat fine in **iTerm2 ** but it displays the complete command as a title but I want the specific argument  or part of the string of command as a title

suppose I run this command in the terminal

> sudo java - jar xyz_service/build/lib/xxx_snapshot.jar

and the terminal title being set as it is but I only want to set **xyz_service** as a title

note: above command always display **update_terminal_cwd** as a title in default bash shell terminal

my other trials which are not working though

```
if [ "$SHELL" = '/bin/bash' ]
then
    case $TERM in
         rxvt|*term)
            set -o functrace
            trap 'echo -ne "\e]0;"; echo -n $BASH_COMMAND; echo -ne "\007"' DEBUG
            export PS1="\e]0;$TERM\007$PS1"
         ;;
    esac
fi
```

this is also not working

```
settitle () {
    export PREV_COMMAND=${PREV_COMMAND}${@}
    echo -ne "\033]0;${PREV_COMMAND}\007"
    export PREV_COMMAND=${PREV_COMMAND}' | '
}

export PROMPT_COMMAND=${PROMPT_COMMAND}';export PREV_COMMAND=""'
```

My environment is:

- macOS HighSierra v **10.13.3**
- iTerm2 **build 2.15**
- shell is bash **v 2.8 (400)**

Can I do this without a wrapper alias in bash that explicitly sets the variable name?